# Xamarin Android Error Handling and Logging

Tags: android, error-handling, xamarin

Just finishing up on an Xamarin Android implementation and the general consensus online is that you cannot trap and handle generic exceptions in Xamarin. From what I can tell, the best you can do is attempt to log the error before completely bailing out of the application (but cannot stop this bail out).

It seems there are only third party options available to dump error logs to a cloud service, something I would prefer not to have to pay for.

Could you please confirm:

1 - Are my comments above accurate?
2 - Are there any reliable free cloud-based services to dump logs to?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. I am not entirely sure there isn't a way to handle generic exceptions.
2. I am using [Raygun](https://raygun.com). They have a good plugin for Xamarin already and it is really easy to install.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out Xamarin Insights
[Xamarin Insights from Xamarin a cloud based error and performance dashboard](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/insights/getting-started/)